# CUDA version on your system does not match the CUDA version torch was compiled with

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pytorch, nvidia

While installing Apex, it may raise an error if the CUDA version on your system does not match the CUDA version torch was compiled with. This raise can be avoided by commenting it here:

> if (bare_metal_version != torch_binary_version): raise RuntimeError(
> "Cuda extensions are being compiled with a version of Cuda that does "
> "not match the version used to compile Pytorch binaries. " "Pytorch
> binaries were compiled with Cuda {}.\n".format(torch.version.cuda)
>
> - "In some cases, a minor-version mismatch will not cause later errors: " "NVIDIA/apex#323 (comment). " "You can try commenting out
>   this check (at your own risk)." )

by default it commented
iam trying to run this on AWS sage maker using ml.g5.12xlarge
unable to get through Please help me with this.
Using python 3.8.10 but the documentation says use Python 3.9 or above is this a typo or am i doing something worng please help.

I followed every instruction from this documentation  https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are facing multiple issues related to CUDA versions and Python compatibility while trying to install Apex and run NVIDIA NeMo on AWS SageMaker. Let's address each of these concerns step by step:

1. CUDA version mismatch:
   The error you mentioned about the CUDA version mismatch is raised by Apex during installation when the CUDA version on your system does not match the CUDA version used to compile PyTorch binaries. Since you are running this on AWS SageMaker, it is possible that the SageMaker environment has a different CUDA version than the one used by Apex.

To resolve this, you have two options:
a. Make sure the CUDA version on your SageMaker instance matches the CUDA version used to compile PyTorch binaries. If it is possible to select a different SageMaker instance type with a matching CUDA version, you can try that.
b. As suggested in the error message, you can try commenting out the version check in the Apex installation code. This should be done at your own risk, as it might lead to compatibility issues later on. If you choose this option, proceed with caution.

2. Python version compatibility:
   The NeMo documentation recommends using Python 3.9 or above. However, you mentioned that you are using Python 3.8.10. While it is always better to follow the recommended Python version, in most cases, minor versions (e.g., Python 3.8 and 3.9) should not cause significant compatibility issues. You can try running NeMo with Python 3.8.10, and it may work fine. If you encounter any specific issues related to Python versions, you can try switching to Python 3.9 to see if that resolves the problem.

Here's what you can do to troubleshoot the installation and execution of NeMo on AWS SageMaker:

1. Check the CUDA version on your SageMaker instance:
   You can run the following command to check the CUDA version:

```bash
nvcc --version
```

2. Ensure that you have properly set up the environment and dependencies required by NeMo, including PyTorch, NVIDIA Apex, etc.
3. Make sure you have followed all the steps in the NeMo documentation correctly.
4. If you are encountering errors during installation or execution, carefully read the error messages and search for any specific solutions or workarounds related to SageMaker in the NeMo issue tracker or relevant forums.
5. If the issues persist, consider reaching out to the NeMo community or the AWS SageMaker support team for further assistance.